# Android NDK binary file size

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm compiling an NDK project using the ndk-build tool. I was wondering if there are any additional compiler flags that I could add to reduce the size of the compiled binary?

My Android.mk file is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := anddown
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := anddown.c src/autolink.c src/buffer.c src/markdown.c src/stack.c html/houdini_href_e.c html/houdini_html_e.c html/html_smartypants.c html/html.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni/src jni/html

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: What is the binary size now? Also, marking the package as non-debuggable in the manifest might help.

Comment: Pretty low, around 100kb, just trying to get the total APK file size down a little more. This represents around 25% of the total size.

How would I go about adding this?

Comment: Under `<application>`, there's `android:debuggable`. If present and `true`, reset to `false` or remove. It makes the compiler add debug symbols to the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure the '-Os' flag is getting passed in CFLAGS.  That enables optimizations that try to reduce binary size.  Also make sure debugging symbols are being stripped from the final binary.